# What technologies should we use to process terra bytes of data in real time?

Tags: java, hadoop, real-time

We have a website which generates MB/TB of data which needs to be mined. What technologies should we use to process terra bytes of data in real time ? Hadoop , Cassandra are good for batch processing; but not for real time.
Real-time; means process the data as it is happening and show reports on that.
Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: With virtually no facts on environments etc., there's only room for speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [the Storm project](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki)? It's used by Twitter. It's like real-time Hadoop.

We use it for one of our stream processing project. It's awesome. Documentation, development, deployment, scalability awesome. We recently ran a 20K message/sec with processing (storing in Cassandra, modifying and broadcasting, calculating mean), it worked reliably and like magic. Definitely worth giving a shot. The mailing list is very friendly, I rarely had to use it to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can process TBs of data with the same technologies as you can process 1 MB of data, but it will take longer.

I don't see how you intend to use the data in "real time" and I suspect you mean real world.

If you mean quickly, then you need to summarise the data for human consumption.  You can only present to the user kilo-bytes or mega-bytes of information at once.

Using memory mapped files can make this more efficient if you have a need to load the data all at once. This can be used to process tens of millions of records per second.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page: http://hadoop.apache.org/

There are listed related frameworks/libraries to work with large amount of data in distributed environment.